# Incorrect shared libraries picked in AIX

Tags: aix, dynamic-linking

While building a particular module, I get the below error:

```
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .MD5_Init
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .SHA1_Init
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .SHA224_Init
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .SHA256_Init
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .SHA384_Init
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .SHA512_Init
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .SHA1_Update
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .SHA1_Final
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .SHA224_Update
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .SHA224_Final
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .SHA256_Update
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .SHA256_Final
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .SHA384_Update
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .SHA384_Final
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .SHA512_Update
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .SHA512_Final
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .MD5_Update
ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .MD5_Final
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
make: *** [entity_test] Error 8
```

I see that these symbols come from openssl's libcrypto.a library:-

```
$ nm openssl-1.0.2f/libcrypto.so|grep SHA512_Final
.SHA512_Final        T         448
SHA512_Final         D        3088          24
SHA512_Final         d        2976           8
.SHA512_Final        U           -
```

I have exported LIBPATH=:$LIBPATH and built with -lcrypto option. However from the dump output, I still do not find the libcrypto.so from openssl being used from ldd output.

```
ldd lru_test
lru_test needs:
         /cb/cb10b/rel/server/lib/libexpat.so
         /usr/lib/libpthread.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
         /usr/lib/libiconv.a(shr4_64.o)
         /cb/cb10b/rel/server/lib/liblog4cxx.so
         /usr/lib/libC.a(shr_64.o)
         /usr/lib/libC.a(shr2_64.o)
         /usr/lib/libC.a(shr3_64.o)
         /usr/lib/libC.a(ansi_64.o)
         /usr/lib/libc.a(shr_64.o)
         /unix
         /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.so
         /usr/lib/libapr-1.so
         /usr/lib/libC.a(shrcore_64.o)
         /usr/lib/libC.a(ansicore_64.o)
         /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr_64.o)
         /usr/lib/libexpat.a(libexpat.so.1)
         /usr/lib/libiconv.a(libiconv.so.2)
ar: 0707-109 Member name libiconv.so.2 does not exist.
dump: /tmp/tmpdir22282828/extract/libiconv.so.2: 0654-106 Cannot open the specified file.
         /usr/lib/libc.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libpthread.a(shr_xpg5.o)
         /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr.o)
         /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_comm.o)

$ dump -H -X32_64 lru_test

lru_test:

                        ***Loader Section***
                      Loader Header Information
VERSION#         #SYMtableENT     #RELOCent        LENidSTR
0x00000001       0x00000117       0x000023b0       0x00000139

#IMPfilID        OFFidSTR         LENstrTBL        OFFstrTBL
0x0000000a       0x00025560       0x00001d5a       0x00025699


                        ***Import File Strings***
INDEX  PATH                          BASE                MEMBER
0      /cb/cb10b/cb/server/lib:/cb/cb10b/rel/server/lib:/opt/IBM/xlmass/8.1.2/lib/aix61:/opt/IBM/xlc/13.1.2/lib:/opt/IBM/xlC/13.1.2/lib:/usr/lib:/lib        
1                                    libexpat.so
2                                    libpthread.a        shr_xpg5_64.o
3                                    libiconv.a          shr4_64.o
4                                    liblog4cxx.so
5                                    libC.a              shr_64.o
6                                    libC.a              shr2_64.o
7                                    libC.a              shr3_64.o
8                                    libC.a              ansi_64.o
9                                    libc.a              shr_64.o
```

While the build has passed, the output from ldd still is quite perplexing.
1. Why does libcrypto.so not appear as a dependency in ldd?
2. However, how is the dependency for the symbols listed above being resolved by the linker?

Comment: can't help with this, but I used to get more eyes on my AIX problems at http://ittoolbox.com . Join the AIX group. There may still be IBM sponsored support forums and other avenues for this level of AIX issue. (note the low number of AIX followers here, vs Linux or Unix). Good luck!

Comment: Your friends are `dump -H -X32_64 <executable_or_sharedobject>` and `dump -Tv -X32_64 <executable_or_sharedobject>`. (A note: you could install your shared libs into standard places like `/usr/local/lib[64]` or `/opt/lib[64]`)

Comment: @Lorinczy Zsigmond I've added the output of dump -H -X32_64. The output of dump -Tv -X32_64  seems to be too long. Is there something specific that I can search/look in output from those commands.

Comment: Well, I don't think I could properly explain here what I'd like to; instead I started to write a little documentation: http://web.axelero.hu/lzsiga/aix-linking.html